# Get email address from Active Directory

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-word

I have Word VBA code which sends a document via mail. The recipient email address is manually written into a textbox and then committed automatically to Outlook.

I want that the email address is automatically set into that textbox by using the name of a person (also textboxes for firstname + lastname), comparing that to the Active Directory and retrieving the appropriate email address.

How to do that in Word VBA?

Comment: have you tried anything on your own? did you find any initial solution in google or anywhere? something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279045/vba-outlook-2010-retrieving-information-from-active-directory) as a first step.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out: it will query back an email based on either a username (name1 - do not pass a second parameter) or first (name1) and last (name2) names.

```
Function UserNameToEmail(name1 As String, Optional name2 As String = "")

    Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    base = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"

    'filter on user objects with the given account name
    fltr = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)"
    If Len(name2) = 0 Then
        fltr = fltr & "(sAMAccountName=" & name1 & "))"
    Else
        fltr = fltr & "(givenName=" & name1 & ")(sn=" & name2 & "))"
    End If

    'add other attributes according to your requirements
    attr = "mail,department,givenName,sn"
    scope = "subtree"

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    If Not rs.EOF Then
      For Each f In rs.Fields
        Debug.Print f.Name & ": " & f.Value
      Next f
      UserNameToEmail = rs.Fields("mail").Value
    End If

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Function
```

FYI- list of ActiveDirectory fields: http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

Comment: This works perfectly and answer's OP's query exactly. S/b accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Outlook Object Model? Callin Recipient.Resolve or Recipeints.ResolveAll will resolve the display names of the message recipients.

If you want to resolve a name to an address without creating a message, use Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipeint.Resolve.